# jQuery UI tabs content border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement jQuery UI tabs in my web app.
I am using ajax functionality so that the tabs are in the main "layout" of the page and each tab contains a different web page.
I want to wrap the content of the tab in aborder, but that the navigation panel of the tab won't be in the border.
I tried putting a border on the main div of the content, but I see only the top border and the rest don't appear.
Any ideas?
[image: Tab content border problem]

Comment: Without seeing your HTML/CSS, my crystal ball guess is that the contents of each panel have a float style on them and there is nothing clearing the container afterwards. i.e. clear:both;

Comment: @Gregg Thanks. The tabs do have a float style on them. I didn't understand what I should do about clearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GW5M2/

vs

http://jsfiddle.net/GW5M2/1/

Answer (score 1):

As Gregg's demo showed, you need a clearing element at the end of the list of floating elements. Make sure the clearing element is not (accidentally) floating (i.e. use `float: none`). So, you would do something like:

```
<div>
  <div style="float:right">foo</div>
  <div style="float:right">bar</div>
  <div style="clear:both; float:none"></div>
</div>
```